# DbUnit Tests con SilkCentral

Tags: test-ng

Estoy intentado ejecutar unos test DbUnit mediante SilkCentral en una máquina virtual remota que hace de servidor de ejecución. El **.class** que quiero ejecutar se encuentra en el directorio `\\p6621va\ucd\ucdmain_TEST\bin\es\bde\aps\ucdmain\ias\tests\AllTests.class` y contiene la suite de los tests que a su vez contiene todos los tests que quiero ejecutar.

Lo primero que necesito es crear un 'Source Control Profile', el cual lo he definido de la siguiente manera:

UNC path: `\\p6624va\UCD`
Working folder: `c:\SilkTempSource`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según la documentación debo especificar en 'UNC path' la ruta absoluta en la máquina virtual (dicha ruta está compartida y he comprobado el acceso a la misma remotamente desde mi equipo).
Además se debe especificar una ruta local en 'Working folder' en la que el servidor de ejecución copiará los archivos fuente.

Source Control Profile : http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.sctm.doc%2FSCTM-ED9457CF-ADDINGUNCSCPROFILES-TSK.html&cp=7_0_1_3_0_1_8_0

El siguien paso es crear el 'Test Container' y asociarle el 'Source control profile' antes creado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En 'Root node' no tengo demasiado claro qué ruta debo especificar. Según la documentación el servidor de ejecución recupera los archivos fuente de los tests incluidos en el container desde el 'Source control profile'. El nodo raíz del 'Source control profile' se establece en el nodo raíz del 'Test container'.

Test container: http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.sctm.doc%2FSCTM-5AEE9AC7-ADDINGTESTCONTAINERS-TSK.html&cp=7_0_1_3_1_0_0

Por último creo un test asociado al 'Test container' recién creado y defino sus propiedades:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el Classpath se debe especificar la ruta relativa a la carpeta de trabajo definida en el 'Source Control Profile'

Classpath: `ucdmain_TEST\bin\es\bde\aps\ucdmain\ias\tests`

Test properties: http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.sctm.doc%2FSCTM-32F41E3A-CONFIGURINGJUNITTESTPROPERTIES-TSK.html

El problema que me devuelve es el siguiente:

```
com.segue.tm.plugins.testlaunch.junit.ju4support.AllTests (0 Failures, 1 Errors, 0 Warnings) 

Detected java version "1.8.0_60".

initializationError (0 Failures, 1 Errors, 0 Warnings) 

Error - No testclasses found in classpath c:\SilkTempSource\ucdmain_TEST\bin\es\bde\aps\ucdmain\ias\tests 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No testclasses found in classpath c:\SilkTempSource\ucdmain_TEST\bin\es\bde\aps\ucdmain\ias\tests 
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) 

~AllTests#initializationError: No testclasses found in classpath c:\SilkTempSource\ucdmain_TEST\bin\es\bde\aps\ucdmain\ias\tests
```

Por lo que entiendo que no se está realizando bien la copia de los ficheros fuente a la ruta local desde el UNC path: `\\p6624va\UCD` al Working folder: `c:\SilkTempSource` declarado en el 'Source Control Profile'.
De momento no especifico un 'Test class' puesto que el error se encuentra en el acceso a la ruta.

Agradezco cualquier aportación, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Cesar, es recomendable que pongas el codigo del error como texto en vez de imagen, así si esa foto desaparece tu pregunta no pierde información. Ademas que en texto podemos copiar y pegar

Comment: Gracias @lois6b ya lo he modificado

Comment: Hola César. ¿Por qué no pruebas a copiar los scripts localmente al servidor de ejecución y utilizar entonces una URL relativa para el classpath? Mira el apartado "Source Control" de este enlace: https://community.microfocus.com/borland/test/silk_central/b/weblog/archive/2015/06/10/test-management-for-selenium-tests-with-silk-central.aspx

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @johnbo. Lo he hecho como me dices y el problema que tengo ahora está en la copia de los archivos fuente al directorio local por parte del servidor de ejecución. He editado la pregunta para detallarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente he conseguido resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

Source Control Profile:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Test container:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Junit Test:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema residía en la especificación tanto del 'Classpath' como del 'Test class'. La ruta de la clase que quería ejecutar era:
`\\p6621va\ucd\ucdmain_TEST\bin\es\bde\aps\ucdmain\ias\tests\AllTests.class`

En 'Test class' se debe especificar el nombre completo de la clase de prueba JUnit, esto quiere decir que hay que especificar el paquete que contiene dicha clase, que en mi caso era `es.bde.aps.ucdmain.ias.tests.AllTests.class`. Por lo tanto en 'Classpath' sólo debía especificar hasta el directorio \bin de la siguiente manera: `.\ucdmain_TEST\bin;`

De esta manera la ruta completa de acceso se compone así:
`c:\SilkTempSource\ucdmain_TEST\bin\es\bde\aps\ucdmain\ias\tests\AllTests.class`,
la cual corresponde con la copia local que hace el servidor de ejecución de los archivos fuente. Además es necesario también indicar las dependencias que tiene la clase test, que en mi caso se encuentran en el directorio `c:\SilkTempSource\ucdmain_TEST\lib`